# Regular expression to find occurrence of uppercase followed by lowercase

Tags: regex

What regular expression can I use for finding occurrences of uppercase followed by lowercase?

For example:

```
ABcDe
```

Here I would be hoping to find the 'B' and the 'D'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use forward lookaheads. You haven't said which "flavour" of regex you're using, so here's a C# example:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[A-Z](?=[a-z])");
string str = "ABcDef";
regex.Replace(str, "?");
Console.WriteLine(str); // outputs "A?c?ef"
```

Additionally, for international characters, you can use [Unicode character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#sectionToggle3):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\p{Lu}(?=\p{Ll})");
```

Comment: The \p should be lowercase, otherwise it means negation.

Comment: Thanks Dean! This is exactly what I needed. Saved me a lot of time as I was quite stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Z][a-z]
```

(assuming English characters only)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
([A-Z])[a-z]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("(?:([A-Z])[a-z])")

strdata = 'ABcDefGHIjk'

print [m.group(1) for m in regex.findinter(strdata) if m.group(1) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can do this:

```
let test_string = "This$IsTheTestForTest_purpose";
test_string.replace(/[\W_]|([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1 ")

// console.log(test_string)
// This Is The Test For Test purpose
```